# jQuery Context Menu, single menu with multiple actions

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, right-click

I am using the following jQuery Context Menu:

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/index.php

The usage is quite simple, in that you create a menu like this

```
var menu1 = [
  {'Option 1':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 1!"); } },
  $.contextMenu.separator,
  {'Option 2':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 2!"); } }
];
$(function() {
  $('.cmenu1').contextMenu(menu1,{theme:'vista'});
});
```

then you simply name the div class with the menu function name, so in this example

The problem I'm facing is that I have around 30 div layers inside table cells, I've classed them all as cmenu1 because I don't want to replicate 30 different menu functions. Essentially I need them to all have the same menu options, but the on click action for each div needs to be different. So for example, if I click option 1 on div1, it should be able to alert me on the div number.

Comment: You can create a loop?

Comment: You just want to report the parent DIV when clicking on a menu item, is this correct?

Comment: putvande, how do you mean? but wouldnt a loop just be like having 30 different menus. i was thinking if there was a way for me to create like an additional function and link it into the div?

DevIshOne, yes but i want to report which div out of the 30 i clicked on. So for example i have:

<div class="cmenu1">div 1</div>
<div class="cmenu1">div 2</div>

Comment: All 30 of the DIVs have class `cmenu1`?

Comment: Yes all 30 of the DIVs have class as cmenu1 but they all have a different id, so class="cmenu1" id="div1" div2 onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var menu1 = [
  {'Option 1':function(menuItem,menu) { var myDIV = $(this).closest("div.cmenu1").attr("id"); alert("You clicked Option 1 inside div id " + myDIV  + " !"); } },
  $.contextMenu.separator,
  {'Option 2':function(menuItem,menu) { var myDIV = $(this).closest("div.cmenu1").attr("id"); alert("You clicked Option 2 inside div id " + myDIV  + " !"); } }
];
$(function() {
  $('.cmenu1').contextMenu(menu1,{theme:'vista'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks DevIshOne, doesnt seem to work, it doesnt give me the name of the Div, i've given each div an ID, can this ID be displayed instead? e.g. <div class="cmenu1" id="div1">

Comment: From the rendered page, could you do a `View Source` and show an example of the entire element `<div class="cmenu1" id="div1">....</div>`??

Comment: I'm going to edit "Option 2" to something else.. let's see if it works better. Also, be sure to change all the single quotes (in my code) to double quotes as they are displayed now. It's a JSON thing and it'd slipped my mind.

Comment: Option 1 works very well, if i add the Option 2 code, then it halts and stops loading.

Comment: Okay.. let's change Option 2 to look like Option 1. I'll edit now.